# Get the first numbers from a string

Tags: c#, string, numbers, substring

I want to get the first instance of numbers in a string.

So I got this input string which could be one of the following:

```
1: "Event: 1 - Some event"
2: "Event 12 -"
3: "Event: 123"
4: "Event: 12 - Some event 3"
```

The output of the input string must be:

```
1: 1
2: 12
3: 123
4: 12
```

I've tried the following methods but none of them gives me exactly what I want.

```
number = new String(input.ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
//This gives me all the numbers in the string

var index = input.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
string substring = input.Substring(index, 4);
number = new string(substring.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
//This gives me first number and then the numbers in the next 4 characters. However it breaks if there is less than 4 characters after the first number.
```

EDIT: A lot of people posted good solutions but I ended up accepting the one I actually used in my code. I wish I could accept more answers!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The correct way to do this with Linq is as follows

```
number = new string(input.SkipWhile(c=>!char.IsDigit(c))
                         .TakeWhile(c=>char.IsDigit(c))
                         .ToArray());
```

Basically skip everything that isn't a digit, then stop taking characters when they are no longer digits.  Note this would stop at punctuation, so it wouldn't pull something like "30.5" out of a string.  If you need to deal with punctuation in the number then regular expressions would be the way to go.  Also note that you don't need to do `ToCharArray` because string implements `IEnumerable<char>` which is all that is required for Linq.

Also you'll have to target .Net 4.0 as that is when they added the `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` extension methods.

Comment: A good solution that works and is slightly faster than using regular expressions. Atleast that is what I've have testet it to be. +1

Comment: yes Regular expressions are a. slow b. can become overly complex and unwieldy to maintain. This is best

Answer (score 11):

It seems to me that you just need a regular expression:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ExtractFirstNumber("Event: 1 - Some event");
        ExtractFirstNumber("Event: 12 -");
        ExtractFirstNumber("Event: 123");
        ExtractFirstNumber("Event: 12 - Some event 3");
        ExtractFirstNumber("Event without a number");
    }

    private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
    static void ExtractFirstNumber(string text)
    {
        var match = regex.Match(text);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Success ? match.Value : "No match");
    }
}
```

The first match will only start at the first digit, and will stop at the first non-digit (or the end of the string). You can use the `Length` and `Index` properties of the match to work out where it was within the string if you need to.

Comment: A good solution that does the job. +1. But this is slightly slower than using linq (results from my own test).

Comment: This solution stops at punctuations. Can't return "1.5" but returns "1" instead.

Comment: @n.Stenvang: So does your sample code. *Nothing* in your question says anything about non-integers. And is performance even a factor here? Again, there's nothing about that in the question - have you benchmarked your actual application to find out whether this piece of code is really significant in the big picture?

Comment: Nothing in my question indicates that I want to return decimal numbers and that's because I don't need it. But others might come across this solution and I just wanted to state to them that it is not able to return decimal numbers in case they need it.
I have not benchmarked my code and performance is not a factor either. Again I'm just stating that it is a bit slower.
Nothing wrong with your solution. It's perfect for what I need it to do!

Answer (score 3):

```
see if this helps
 var input = "sdmfnasldkfjhasdlfkjh234sdf234234";
        var index = input.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
        string substring = input.Substring(index); // this will give rest of the string.
        number = new string(substring.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());

        //number will have 234
```

Comment: While not the best solution it does show the OP where they went wrong in their second attempt. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular expression to get the result.

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details about regular expression.

```
    String s1= "Event: 1 - Some event";
    String s2=  "Event 12 -";
    String s3= "Event: 123";
    String s4=  "Event: 12 - Some event 3";


    String result1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s1, @"\d+").Value;
    String result2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s2, @"\d+").Value;
    String result3 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s3, @"\d+").Value;
    String result4 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s4, @"\d+").Value;
```